# Osmdroid XYTileSource passing X and Y paramaters

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I am really new in this routing and maps area. I have a basic, maybe stupid, question. I use osmdroid to show a tile from a URL that looks like this

http://tile01-cdn.maptoolkit.net/terrain/15/17789/11515.png

Where 15 represents the **zoom**,
17789 the **X** value and
11515 the **Y** value

Now when I want to use osmdroid to show this tile in the map I don't know what kind of TileSource should I use. The most obvious is the `XYTileSource` but the constructor does not have any x y parameters to pass, but I see on the internet a lot of questions/answers where people use the same object but with a different constructor. I am guessing here that the code has changed in the lib. The current constructor:

```
XYTileSource(String aName, int aZoomMinLevel, int aZoomMaxLevel, int aTileSizePixels, String aImageFilenameEnding, String[] aBaseUrl)
```

So my question is how can I show this tile map of mine in the osmdroid map, what kind of `ITileSource` should I use? Should I implement my own custom one?

this is how I tried to do it:

```
final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("Maverik", 15, 17789, 11515, ".png", new String[] {"http://tile01-cdn.maptoolkit.net/terrain/"});
        tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
```

and I get an empty `MapView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of osmdroid is to display world map - with a lot of tiles. And to display the appropriate tiles depending on where the "map view" is centered (this center being defined with: a latitude, a longitude, and a zoom level).

If this is also what you want:

1) As examples, look at default tile sources included in osmdroid, in [TileSourceFactory](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/TileSourceFactory.java)

2) Then you could try something like:

```
OnlineTileSourceBase tileSource = new XYTileSource("Maverik", 
  0, 17, 
  256, ".png", 
  new String[] {
    "http://tile01-cdn.maptoolkit.net/terrain/", 
    "http://tile02-cdn.maptoolkit.net/terrain/",
    "http://tile03-cdn.maptoolkit.net/terrain/"
  });
mapView.setTileSource(tileSource);
```

Comment: Thx for the hints, I tried using the default tile sources before I asked this question, for example: `mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT);` but with no result. I still always get an empty grid. I have added all the permissions in the manifest that I found on Q&As with the same problem.

Comment: Start with the basic "Hello osmdroid World" tuto (https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library). If you still have the grey grid, then the issue is in your project config.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want ton consult the osmdroid wiki and the source for the sample application. There's tons of examples on how to use just about every tile source that we know of. We're also adding more as they are discovered.

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki

You don't need to worry about X and Y coordinates. They actually aren't lat/lon coordinates but are grid references. Open Street Maps, and many other tile sources, use the same or similar tile coordinate system. Start with the world in one image. Zoom =1 divide it into 4 parts. That's your X,Y and Zoom coordinates. Zoom =2 level, divid the four tiles we started with into 4 again, and we have 16 tiles.

Comment: Thx for the explanation, I already went through the wiki. One of the reasons why I chose osmdroid is because of the documentation :)